# How to order JFrame components?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create user interface, but i could not do ordered components. How to order my JPanel component like second picture, is there any idea?

my codes result is that
[image]

i want to create like that
[image]

here is my java codes

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class ApplicationWindow2 {

    private JFrame mainJFrame;
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JPanel bottomPanel;


    public ApplicationWindow2(){

        mainJFrame = new JFrame("setupbox");

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mainJFrame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        mainJFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int) mainJFrame.getMaximumSize().getWidth()-1,(int) mainJFrame.getMaximumSize().getHeight()-1));
        mainJFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        int windowHeight = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
        int windowWidth = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
        mainJFrame.setLocation((windowWidth-mainJFrame.getWidth())/2, (windowHeight-mainJFrame.getHeight())/2);//

        // components
        mainJFrame.getContentPane().add(getTopPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        mainJFrame.getContentPane().add(getCenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainJFrame.getContentPane().add(getBottomPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        mainJFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainJFrame.pack();

    }

    private JPanel getTopPanel(){

        if (topPanel == null){

            topPanel = new JPanel();
            topPanel.add(new JLabel("top panel"));
        }

        return topPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getBottomPanel(){

        if(bottomPanel == null){
            bottomPanel = new JPanel();
            bottomPanel.add(new Label("bottom panel"));
        }

        return bottomPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getCenterPanel(){

        if(centerPanel == null){

            centerPanel = new JPanel();
            centerPanel.setSize(new Dimension((int) mainJFrame.getMaximumSize().getWidth()-100,(int) mainJFrame.getMaximumSize().getHeight()-100));
            centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

            BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
            centerPanel.setLayout(boxLayout);

            centerPanel.add(getTest());
            centerPanel.add(getTest1());
            centerPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(30));
            centerPanel.add(getTest());

        }

        return centerPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getTest(){

        JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        testPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(getCenterPanel().getWidth(), 40));
        testPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        JCheckBox box1 = new JCheckBox("asdasdasdasdasdasd");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        testPanel.add(box1, c);

        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("lbl3asdssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
        l3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,30));
        l3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        testPanel.add(l3, c);

        return testPanel;

    }

    private JPanel getTest1(){

        JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        testPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(getCenterPanel().getWidth(), 40));
        testPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        JCheckBox box1 = new JCheckBox("aass1133");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        testPanel.add(box1, c);

        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("lbl3as");
        l3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,30));
        l3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        testPanel.add(l3, c);

        return testPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: `JTable`?  `MigLayout`?

Comment: Can we set cells's different size in migLayout? and how to we import intellij? it seems like good

Comment: I've not personally used `MigLayout`, but it's been suggested that it can solve these kinds of issues. Basically, you need to download the Jar file and include it within your project. Not familiar with intellij either :P

Comment: thanks for your suggest, i will try it :D

Comment: There is a [MigLayout Demo](http://www.miglayout.com/swingdemoapp.jnlp) . In it, there are several examples how to set the cell size. You can for example use a percentage of a component, use a fixed cell size etc.

Comment: it is useful for me , but i have some examples like that. forexample i can not set miglayout size. is there a document different from [QuickStart.pdf]http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem with MigLayout, and here is my code
[image]

```
private JPanel getTest1(){

        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug");
        JPanel content = new JPanel(layout);
        content.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(getCenterPanel().getWidth(), 40));

        JCheckBox a1 = new JCheckBox("d");
        content.add(a1, "gapright 10, height 30, width 250, cell 0 0");

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        content.add(label, "gapright 10, height 30, width 30, cell 1 0");

        JButton btn = new JButton("try again");
        content.add(btn,"height 30, width 80, cell 2 0" );

        return content;

    }
```